# Prove every integer is of the form $5k+r$ with $0\le r<5$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

I have came across this question from my text book:

Prove or disprove: any integer $n$ is of the form: $5k$, $5k + 1$, $5k + 2$, $5k + 3$ or $5k + 4$ for some integer $k$.

I'm not sure what would be the appropriate method of proof here. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You don't always need a "method of proof" such as proof by contradiction, proof by contrapositive, etc. Eventually you do actually have to work with something. So don't ever ignore the "method" of analyzing the situation and creating a direct argument that the statement is true.

Comment: The proof will depend on what you already accept as true, for example: the division theorem, or the laws of modular arithmetic.

Comment: There are a lot of ways of proving the statement. Pick one and start.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the Euclidean Algorithm ( I mean the Division Algorithm ): Given $n$-an interger. Divide $n$ by $5$: $n = 5q+r$, then $r$ as the remainder, it must be non-negative, and less than $5$. Thus: $r = 0,1,2,3,4$. So $n = 5q, 5q+1,5q+2,5q+3$ or $5q+4$, proving the statement.

Comment: How do we know the EA works?

Comment: This isn't even the Euclidena algorithm, it is just the division algorithm.  But to answer the question that I think @vadim123 is asking, assuming we take for granted things like the archemedean property of the real numbers, we can write $n=kq_0+r_0$ where $q_0=0, r_0=n$, and if $r_i\geq k$, set $q_{i+1}=q_i+1, r_{i+1}=r_i-k.$  Then we always have $n=kq_i+r_i$, and eventually we will have a solution with $0\leq r_i <k$.

Answer (score 6):

We can prove this for $n\ge 0$ by induction on $n$.  We first check that $n=0=5k$, for $k=0$, as our base case.  Suppose now, our inductive hypothesis, that $n-1=5k+j$, for some $0\le j\le 4$.  If $0\le j\le 3$, then $n=5k+(j+1)$, is of the desired form.  If instead $j=4$, then $n=5(k+1)+0=(5k+4)+1=(n-1)+1$.

I leave those $n<0$ for you to do; they can be done again by induction on $|n|$.

Answer (score 2):

It is a direct consequence of [Euclidean division theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division#Statement_of_the_theorem) (I've changed it a bit):

> Given integers $a,b$ with $b> 0$, there exist integers $q,r$ such that $a=bq+r$ and $0\le r<b$.

Proof: $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions), i.e. largest integer smaller than or equal to $x$:

$$\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\rfloor\le \frac{a}{b}< \lfloor\frac{a}{b}\rfloor+1$$

$$\iff 0\le \frac{a}{b}-\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\rfloor< 1$$

$$\iff 0\le a-b\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\rfloor< b$$

$$\iff a=b\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\rfloor+r$$

for some $0\le r< b$. QED. So for any $a\in\Bbb Z$ we can find $q,r\in\Bbb Z$ with $0\le r<5$ such that $a=5q+r$.

Answer (score 1):

Use long division: any integer $n$ has a quotient $q$ and a remainder $r$, $0\le r<5$, upon division by $5$, and these are unique.

Comment: How do we know long division works?

Comment: ??? Because of the properties of $\mathbf N$. Not sure to see what's your objection?

Comment: My objection is that the proof of long division is harder than the proof of the original question.

Comment: Yes, but everyone knows it since elementary school; that's why I mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

Write the number in decimal and consider the last digit: $n=10m+d$, where $d\in \{0,1,2,\dots,9\}$.

If $d < 5$, then $n=5k+r$, for $k=2m$ and $r=d$.

If $d \ge 5$, then $n=5k+r$, for $k=2m+1$ and $r=d-5$.